# $V = V_1 + V_2$ confusion? Why is my "proof "incorrect?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, voltage

[image]

Why isn't $V= V_1 + V_2$?
$V=V_a - V_c = V_a - V_b + V_b - V_c$, $V_a - V_b= V_1$ and $V_b - V_c = V_2$
Doesn't that prove that $V = V_1 + V_2$?

Regardless of $V_3$,

If i'm wrong , is there a way to obtain $V$ in terms of $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$

Comment: According to your diagram $V$ should be zero, since $V_A=V_C$.

Comment: how?if you're talking about the middle one on the left not connected it was a misstype i'm sorry

Comment: The three devices all have the same voltage across since they are parallel connected.  Note that points A and C are the *same* circuit node and all three devices connect to that node.  Further, all three devices connect to node B.  Thus, there are only two nodes in this circuit and just one actual voltage which is the voltage across the parallel connected devices.

Answer (score 1):

Actually V=0!

Notice that the left branch shorted the right one, because the points A & C are the same, thus Va = Vc.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your circuit is equivalent to this:

[image]